# How to get status from joining two columns in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two queries and individually both are working properly.

Query 1 :

```
select users.created_at, users.name, users.email, users.image, users.is_online, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.friend_id where users.id != 18 and friends.user_id = 18
```

Output

```
  created_at |    name     |        email               |      image      | is_online | user_id | friend_id | accept 
 ------------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------
  2020-03-24 | yashyashwi  | yashyashwi@gmail.com       | 1596540233.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         2 |  0 
  2020-03-25 | Jesly Benny | benny@gmail.com            | 1596540244.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         4 |  2 
  2020-03-26 | Jesly Benny | kirvvtibhardwaj090@gmail.co| 1596540334.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         7 |  0
```

Query 2 :

```
select users.id, users.name, users.email, users.image, users.created_at, users.is_online, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.user_id where users.id != 18 and friends.friend_id = 18
```

Output

```
  created_at |    name     |        email               |      image      | is_online | user_id | friend_id | accept 
 ------------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------
  2020-03-27 | Zasika      | Zasika@gmail.com           | 1596880233.jpeg | 0         |      5  |         18 |  0
```

I just want to add both the tables

Expected output :

```
  created_at |    name     |        email               |      image      | is_online | user_id | friend_id | accept 
 ------------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------
  2020-03-24 | yashyashwi  | yashyashwi@gmail.com       | 1596540233.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         2 |  0 
  2020-03-25 | Jesly Benny | benny@gmail.com            | 1596540244.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         4 |  2 
  2020-03-26 | Jesly Benny | kirvvtibhardwaj090@gmail.co| 1596540334.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         7 |  0 
  2020-03-27 | Zasika      | Zasika@gmail.com           | 1596880233.jpeg | 0         |      5  |         18 |  0
```

Tried query

```
select users.id, users.name, users.email, users.image, users.created_at, users.is_online, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.friend_id where users.id != $user_id and (friends.user_id = $user_id or friends.user_id is NULL) UNION select users.id, users.name, users.email, users.image, users.created_at, users.is_online, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.user_id where users.id != $user_id and (friends.friend_id = $user_id or friends.friend_id is NULL) order by id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `union` to combine the returned rows from your queries.

Keep in mind that you will need to `select` your columns in the same order in both statements.

Comment: I have tried with UNION, but the rows are repeating twice when tried with null

Comment: Please check the above "Tried query",